# Meteor.publish() - how to get documents by free text

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I trying to get documents by free text.
This part, that getting data by field works OK and returns data:

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function(){
    return Messages.find({ discussion_id: "discus_id_87" });
});
```

This one doesn't work:

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function(){
    return Messages.find({ $text: { $search: "Some text" } });
});
```

Returns an ERROR:

```
 Error: Exception while polling query {"collectionName":"messages","selector":{"$text":{"$search":"Some text"}},"options":{"transform":null}}: Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=meteor.messages limit=0 skip=0
```

This is an example from mongoDB [$text](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

```
db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "bake coffee -cake" } } )
```

What I'm doing wrong?
How to get documents by free text?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your mongo database is version 2.6. This is a relatively new MongoDB feature.

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10, but in application: mongo@1.1.0.  How it was implemented on older versions?

Comment: In older versions, the syntax was slightly different & it required a setting in mongodb.conf to enable it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your mongo database is version 2.6. This is a relatively new MongoDB feature.

Also, you are required to create an index:

```
Meteor.startup(function (){
    Messages._ensureIndex({"$**": "text"}, {"name": "searchIndex"}); 
});
```

More info here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/